# What is the different between hibernate and queryDSL? what the role queryDSL in MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I search on Google but not found! I read that but not understand

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'will find documentation about queryDSL :
https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-querydsl

Hibernate use a query specific language : HQL, this is not a dsl from java program it's just string like SQL.
queryDSL will generate code and create a real Domain Specific Language in java to query your entities.